# How to increment a variable in beamer slide?

Tags: calculations

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Warsaw}
}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AtBeginSection[] 
{
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
 }
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \t in {1,...,40}
    {
        \only<\t>{\node [circle,draw] (a) at (22:11) {\t};}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have a blank frame in the first slide then I start counting.

I want exactly this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \t in {1,...,40}
    {
        \only<\t+1>{\node [circle,draw] (a) at (22:11) {\t};}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But this is does not work. I think the problem is with `\t+1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably a whole host of packages that could help here. However, the following is sufficient to evaluate the expression:

```
\number\numexpr\t+1\relax
```

Here's the "complete" context:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \t in {1,...,40}
  {%
    \only<\number\numexpr\t+1\relax>{\node [circle,draw] (a) at (22:11) {\t};}%
  }%
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note the occasional (sometimes necessary, not in your example though) use of `%` at line ends. For more on this, see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: Thanks. Where should I put the command `\number\numexpr\t+1\relax`?

Answer (score 4):

You could try a conditional: `\ifnum\t = 1 \else \only<\t>...\fi`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Warsaw}
}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AtBeginSection[] 
{
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
 }
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \t in {0,1,...,40}
    {
      \ifnum\t = 1
      \else
      \only<\t>{\node [circle,draw] (a) at (22:11) {\t};}
      \fi
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. With this I will have on slide 2 number 2, on slide 3 number 3 etc. I want to have on slide 2 number 1, on slide 3 number 2 etc.